# Necessary to `import React from 'react'` when using styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, styled-components

If I have a pure component that just takes some props and returns some jsx which is made up of components created 100% with `styled-components`, is it necessary to `import React from 'react'`?

I'm receiving an `eslint` error: `react/react-in-jsx-scope` because currently I'm not importing `React from 'react'`, but my code still works just fine. This reason caused me to question whether or not I should be importing React here.

Here's a pretty basic example of what my pure component file looks like:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

// pure function
const Block = props => {
  return (
    <BlockOuter>
      <BlockInner>{props.children}</BlockInner>
    </BlockOuter>
  )
}

// styled component
const BlockOuter = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  height: ${props => props.height || 400}px;
  width: ${props => props.width}px;
`

// styled component
const BlockInner = styled.div`
  overflow: auto;
`
```

Comment: since react v16 you don't have to import it. i guess eslint is not up to date with this change.

Comment: @Sagivb.g Do you have a link to the changelog for that update?

Comment: its not quite clear, but since you [can return a string or fragments](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#new-render-return-types-fragments-and-strings) then a stateless component like so, will be just as any other normal function isn't it? and there is [this statement in their docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#eslint) about the ESLINT upgrade needed. i remember reading about it somewhere but can't find it now.  but as for your example i think you should import react to support the jsx.

Answer (score 1):

Since React V16 [you can return a string from your components](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#new-render-return-types-fragments-and-strings).
So in some situations, a stateless component that returns a string will be just like any other component:

```
export const Hello = ({ name }) => `${name}`;
```

No need for `react` here.
Of course you will need `react` when you are using `JSX`.

[Here is a small example to demonstrate it](https://codesandbox.io/s/xv7w2630vp).
*I'm not using a stack-snippet because it doesn't support files structure.*

[As for the eslint](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#eslint), i guess it's not [up to date](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9662) with the current version of react.

Comment: I guess at the end of the day its really just an eslint rule that is causing my confusion. Code still works fine, and I believe that using a styled-component doesn't require the importing of React because they abstract React after from you so it's really already being used by the library.

Comment: Also, I don't think returning a string is something I desire just to satisfy a linting rule. I'll just go ahead an import it.